# MySQL Workbench 5.6 - Synchronize Model option missing under Database menu

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to perform Database Synchronization in MySQL. Normally there is an option below in red:

[image]

However I am missing the following options even though I have a proper schema selected within the workbench:

[image]

How else can I navigate to the Synchronization wizard?

Answer (score 1):

"Synchronize Model" is a feature of the model viewer - as can be seen in the top screenshot. You are trying to look for it in the database viewer.

Load your model and look for "Database" -> "Synchronize Model" there.

Comment: gee. been looking forever. thought i was going crazy as i've used it loads before. thanks!